# Dell vostro 1540 touchpad shaking/moving along a millimeter distance Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: drivers, dell, touchpad

its a big pain as my pointer is shaking while i point at some buttons or try to scroll. my touchpad works fine on another installation(elementary os). so i did xinput on terminal and found the third line where it is written "AlpsPS/2 ALPS DualPoint Stick" in my ubuntu installition was somthing different in elementary os. And for the most important part, this was not from the start! it started after i installed elementary os environment on ubuntu from ppa. pointer suddenly started shaking and now its this. i removed/purged elementary but the problem still exists :'( .